# How to specify option for connection to windows/samba share for mounting?

Tags: linux-mint, mount, samba, nemo

There is a windows share on my network that I can access using

```
smbclient //192.168.1.1/MyShare --option="client lanman auth = yes" --option="client ntlmv2 auth = no" --option="client min protocol = NT1" -U user
```

The three options are necessary (lanman, no ntlmv2, and force smbv1) or connection is rejected.
Using nemo assistant for connecting to a server (`file --> Connect to server`), how can I pass theses three options?

Alternatively, I could use `mount` (something like `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/MyShare ~/TEST [...]`), but I can't find the right arguments to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/MyShare ~/TEST -o vers=1.0
```